# Intel XDK HTML Android app, run in background?

Tags: android, audio, mobile, background, intel-xdk

So I've created a 'Sound App' that needs to run when the phone is locked.. After a minute of being locked the sound just cuts out. Anyone suggest a fix?

The app is created out of basic HTML5, css & js. Audio needs to continue playing when the phone is locked.

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a plugin that provides a background service. In order to preserve battery, mobile devices do not normally allow applications to continue to run once they lose focus. After a short period of time they are paused, and if RAM is required to run other apps, they might be stopped entirely. See the pause/resume events for a little more info: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause

Here's a project from devgeeks, who is an accomplished Cordova developer, regarding background audio on iOS: https://github.com/devgeeks/ExampleHTML5AudioStreaming -- also, this blog by Andrew Trice may be of value, he is also an experienced Cordova developer: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/01/25/low-latency-polyphonic-audio-in-phonegap

You might want to search for "cordova phonegap app background audio" for more solutions.